# postfix rejects all EMails Recipient address rejected: User unknown inlocal recipient table

Tags: postfix, ldap, dovecot, samba4

Hi Together I've got a problem with my postfix server and i can't solve it. I set up a local mailserver with dovecot and postfix to receive e-mail over my own domain. It worked fine till i tried to install sogo and managesieve. Now every mail i send to my domain is rejected with the error that the user can't be found in local user tables:

```
 550 5.1.1 <user@example.de>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown inlocal recipient table
```

Here's my  sudo cat /var/log/mail.log | grep postfix

```
Dec 14 14:22:30 hermes postfix/master[2803]: reload -- version 2.11.3, configuration /etc/postfix
Dec 14 14:22:30 hermes postfix/anvil[3676]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:74.125.82.41) at     Dec 14 14:22:28
Dec 14 14:22:30 hermes postfix/anvil[3676]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:74.125.82.41) at     Dec 14 14:22:28
Dec 14 14:22:30 hermes postfix/anvil[3676]: statistics: max cache size 1 at     Dec 14 14:22:28
Dec 14 14:23:18 hermes postfix/smtpd[3788]: connect from mail-wm0-f47.google.com[74.125.82.47]
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_create
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://127.0.0.1:389)
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_sasl_bind
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_send_initial_request
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_int_open_connection
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_connect_to_host: TCP 127.0.0.1:389
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_new_socket: 12
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_prepare_socket: 12
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 127.0.0.1:389
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 12 tm: 10 async: 0
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_ndelay_on: 12
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: attempting to connect:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: connect errno: 115
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_int_poll: fd: 12 tm: 10
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_is_sock_ready: 12
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_ndelay_off: 12
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_pvt_connect: 0
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_open_defconn: successful
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_send_server_request
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_scanf fmt ({it) ber:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_scanf fmt ({i) ber:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_flush2: 95 bytes to sd 12
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_result ld 0x80288c10 msgid 1
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: wait4msg ld 0x80288c10 msgid 1 (timeout 10000000 usec)
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: wait4msg continue ld 0x80288c10 msgid 1 all 1
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ** ld 0x80288c10 Connections:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: * host: 127.0.0.1  port: 389  (default)
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:   refcnt: 2  status: Connected
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:   last used: Mon     Dec 14 14:23:19 2015
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ** ld 0x80288c10 Outstanding Requests:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:  * msgid 1,  origid 1, status InProgress
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:    outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:   ld 0x80288c10 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ** ld 0x80288c10 Response Queue:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:    Empty
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:   ld 0x80288c10 response count 0
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x80288c10 msgid 1 all 1
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x80288c10 NULL
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_int_select
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: read1msg: ld 0x80288c10 msgid 1 all 1
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_get_next
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 12 contents:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: read1msg: ld 0x80288c10 msgid 1 message type bind
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_scanf fmt ({eAA) ber:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: read1msg: ld 0x80288c10 0 new referrals
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 0x80288c10 msgid 1
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: request done: ld 0x80288c10 msgid 1
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: res_errno: 0, res_error: <>, res_matched: <>
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_free_request (origid 1, msgid 1)
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_parse_result
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_scanf fmt ({iAA) ber:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_scanf fmt (}) ber:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_msgfree
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_search_ext
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: put_filter: "(&(objectClass=*)(mail=googlemail.com))"
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: put_filter: AND
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: put_filter_list "(objectClass=*)(mail=googlemail.com)"
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: put_filter: "(objectClass=*)"
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: put_filter: simple
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: put_simple_filter: "objectClass=*"
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: put_filter: "(mail=googlemail.com)"
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: put_filter: simple
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: put_simple_filter: "mail=googlemail.com"
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_send_initial_request
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_send_server_request
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_scanf fmt ({it) ber:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_scanf fmt ({) ber:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_flush2: 103 bytes to sd 12
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_result ld 0x80288c10 msgid 2
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: wait4msg ld 0x80288c10 msgid 2 (timeout 10000000 usec)
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: wait4msg continue ld 0x80288c10 msgid 2 all 1
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ** ld 0x80288c10 Connections:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: * host: 127.0.0.1  port: 389  (default)
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:   refcnt: 2  status: Connected
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:   last used: Mon     Dec 14 14:23:19 2015
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ** ld 0x80288c10 Outstanding Requests:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:  * msgid 2,  origid 2, status InProgress
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:    outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:   ld 0x80288c10 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ** ld 0x80288c10 Response Queue:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:    Empty
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:   ld 0x80288c10 response count 0
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x80288c10 msgid 2 all 1
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x80288c10 NULL
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_int_select
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: read1msg: ld 0x80288c10 msgid 2 all 1
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_get_next
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 12 contents:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: read1msg: ld 0x80288c10 msgid 2 message type search-result
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_scanf fmt ({eAA) ber:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: read1msg: ld 0x80288c10 0 new referrals
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 0x80288c10 msgid 2
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: request done: ld 0x80288c10 msgid 2
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: res_errno: 0, res_error: <>, res_matched: <>
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_free_request (origid 2, msgid 2)
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_parse_result
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_scanf fmt ({iAA) ber:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_scanf fmt (}) ber:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_msgfree
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_search_ext
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: put_filter: "(&(objectClass=*)(mail=example.de))"
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: put_filter: AND
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: put_filter_list "(objectClass=*)(mail=example.de)"
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: put_filter: "(objectClass=*)"
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: put_filter: simple
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: put_simple_filter: "objectClass=*"
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: put_filter: "(mail=example.de)"
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: put_filter: simple
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: put_simple_filter: "mail=example.de"
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_send_initial_request
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_send_server_request
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_scanf fmt ({it) ber:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_scanf fmt ({) ber:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_flush2: 101 bytes to sd 12
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_result ld 0x80288c10 msgid 3
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: wait4msg ld 0x80288c10 msgid 3 (timeout 10000000 usec)
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: wait4msg continue ld 0x80288c10 msgid 3 all 1
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ** ld 0x80288c10 Connections:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: * host: 127.0.0.1  port: 389  (default)
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:   refcnt: 2  status: Connected
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:   last used: Mon     Dec 14 14:23:19 2015
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ** ld 0x80288c10 Outstanding Requests:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:  * msgid 3,  origid 3, status InProgress
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:    outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:   ld 0x80288c10 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ** ld 0x80288c10 Response Queue:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:    Empty
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug:   ld 0x80288c10 response count 0
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x80288c10 msgid 3 all 1
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x80288c10 NULL
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_int_select
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: read1msg: ld 0x80288c10 msgid 3 all 1
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_get_next
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 12 contents:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: read1msg: ld 0x80288c10 msgid 3 message type search-result
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_scanf fmt ({eAA) ber:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: read1msg: ld 0x80288c10 0 new referrals
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 0x80288c10 msgid 3
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: request done: ld 0x80288c10 msgid 3
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: res_errno: 0, res_error: <>, res_matched: <>
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_free_request (origid 3, msgid 3)
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_parse_result
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_scanf fmt ({iAA) ber:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ber_scanf fmt (}) ber:
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/trivial-rewrite[3792]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_msgfree
Dec 14 14:23:19 hermes postfix/smtpd[3788]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-wm0-f47.google.com[74.125.82.47]: 550 5.1.1 <user@example.de>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table; from=<user@googlemail.com> to=<user@example.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-wm0-f47.google.com>
```

What me puzzles is, that only my domain name is given to the mail=filter in ldap...

output of postconf -n:

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = mail/
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
mydestination = regniflow.de, hermes, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = regniflow.de
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Raspbian)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_mailbox_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap/accountsmap.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

and thats my accountmap.cf

```
server_host = 127.0.0.1
search_base = ou=Email_Users,dc=regniflow,dc=de
query_filter = (&(objectClass=*)(mail=%s))
result_attribute = uid
bind = yes
bind_dn = CN=adminAccount,OU=ServiceAccounts,DC=example,DC=de
bind_pw = *******
debuglevel = 1
```

my local samba domain is working and i can successfully query for the mail field...
Has someone an idea why my server now rejects mails? I can't figuere it out and the solutions i found provide only informaition for relaying hosts but mine is the final destination for mails to the domain. Maybe it's a minor thing and i am only too blind to see the obvious
Thanks in advance!
Timo

Comment: Certainly, we don't know what there is inside you LDAP database. If it's only test and example addresses, can you post them?

Comment: i found the solution the local_recipient_maps settung must be left empty to disable checking. Tank you very much. As for the problem with getting no result with an ldap request: I set the ldap field mail to the email-adress of the account - with apache directory studio the search filter works but postfix finds an empty result